# Albert launcher crashes (?) on linux Mint

Tags: linux, albert

I'm using Albert launcher on linux Mint 20.2, and some time after I launch it, I just notice it's not running anymore. Don't know if it crashed or something else killed it. In a different pc with same OS everything is fine...
Any suggestions?

Addition1: I tried launching Albert from terminal, and among the things listed there was:

```
[warn:core] Application has not been terminated graciously.
```

Addition2: This is what the terminal showed when it crashed this time

```
12:32:16 [debg:core] ========== SESSION SETUP STARTED ==========
12:32:16 [debg:core] TIME:      1 µs SESSION SETUP [org.albert.extension.applications]
12:32:16 [debg:core] TIME:      0 µs SESSION SETUP [org.albert.extension.files]
12:32:16 [debg:core] TIME:      1 µs SESSION SETUP [org.albert.extension.system]
12:32:16 [debg:core] TIME:      1 µs SESSION SETUP [org.albert.extension.websearch]
12:32:16 [debg:core] TIME:      0 µs SESSION SETUP [org.albert]
12:32:16 [debg:core] TIME:    201 µs SESSION SETUP OVERALL
12:32:16 [debg:core] ========== QUERY:   ==========
12:32:16 [debg:core] TIME:    225 µs SESSION TEARDOWN OVERALL
12:32:16 [debg:core] TIME:      7 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.files]
12:32:16 [debg:core] TIME:      4 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.system]
12:32:16 [debg:core] TIME:    245 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.applications]
12:32:16 [debg:core] TIME:      2 µs MATCHES [org.albert]
12:32:16 [debg:core] TIME:   5094 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.websearch]
12:32:16 [debg:core] TIME:  41937 µs QUERY OVERALL
12:32:18 [debg:core] ========== QUERY: ד  ==========
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:    126 µs SESSION TEARDOWN OVERALL
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:     16 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.system]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:    143 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.files]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:    193 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.applications]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:      3 µs MATCHES [org.albert]
12:32:18 [debg:core] ========== QUERY: דה  ==========
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:     88 µs SESSION TEARDOWN OVERALL
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:      5 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.system]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:     91 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.applications]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:      2 µs MATCHES [org.albert]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:    160 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.files]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:   3288 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.websearch]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:   5731 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.websearch]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:   3711 µs QUERY OVERALL
12:32:18 [debg:core] ========== QUERY: דה=  ==========
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:    173 µs SESSION TEARDOWN OVERALL
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:      9 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.system]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:    147 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.files]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:    300 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.applications]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:      6 µs MATCHES [org.albert]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:     23 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.websearch]
12:32:18 [debg:core] TIME:  16475 µs QUERY OVERALL
12:32:19 [debg:core] ========== QUERY: דה  ==========
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:    112 µs SESSION TEARDOWN OVERALL
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:     76 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.files]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:      3 µs MATCHES [org.albert]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:     81 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.applications]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:      3 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.system]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:    108 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.websearch]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:   7493 µs QUERY OVERALL
12:32:19 [debg:core] ========== QUERY: ד  ==========
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:    192 µs SESSION TEARDOWN OVERALL
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:    209 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.applications]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:      5 µs MATCHES [org.albert]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:      6 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.system]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:    166 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.websearch]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:    289 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.files]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:  16246 µs QUERY OVERALL
12:32:19 [debg:core] ========== QUERY:   ==========
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:     83 µs SESSION TEARDOWN OVERALL
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:      5 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.files]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:      1 µs MATCHES [org.albert]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:      2 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.system]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:     49 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.websearch]
12:32:19 [debg:core] TIME:    421 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.applications]
12:32:20 [debg:core] TIME:  20054 µs QUERY OVERALL
12:32:20 [debg:core] ========== QUERY: s  ==========
12:32:20 [debg:core] TIME:    207 µs SESSION TEARDOWN OVERALL
12:32:20 [debg:core] TIME:    232 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.applications]
12:32:20 [debg:core] TIME:    263 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.system]
12:32:20 [debg:core] TIME:      5 µs MATCHES [org.albert]
12:32:20 [debg:core] TIME:    166 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.websearch]
12:32:20 [debg:core] TIME:   4279 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.files]
12:32:20 [debg:core] TIME:   5910 µs QUERY OVERALL
12:32:21 [debg:core] ========== QUERY: sc  ==========
12:32:21 [debg:core] TIME:    248 µs SESSION TEARDOWN OVERALL
12:32:21 [debg:core] TIME:    159 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.applications]
12:32:21 [debg:core] TIME:      7 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.system]
12:32:21 [debg:core] TIME:      5 µs MATCHES [org.albert]
12:32:21 [debg:core] TIME:    156 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.websearch]
12:32:21 [debg:core] TIME:    246 µs MATCHES [org.albert.extension.files]
12:32:21 [debg:core] TIME:  14546 µs QUERY OVERALL
12:32:21 [info:default] Detached process started successfully. PID: 51089 ("sh", "-c", "gnome-screenshot --interactive")
12:32:21 [debg:core] ========== SESSION TEARDOWN STARTED ==========
12:32:21 [debg:core] TIME:      0 µs SESSION TEARDOWN [org.albert.extension.applications]
12:32:21 [debg:core] TIME:      0 µs SESSION TEARDOWN [org.albert.extension.files]
12:32:21 [debg:core] TIME:      0 µs SESSION TEARDOWN [org.albert.extension.system]
12:32:21 [debg:core] TIME:      0 µs SESSION TEARDOWN [org.albert.extension.websearch]
12:32:21 [debg:core] TIME:      0 µs SESSION TEARDOWN [org.albert]
12:32:21 [fatal:default] SQL ERROR: INSERT INTO execution (query_id, handler_id, runtime) VALUES (:query_id, :handler_id, :runtime); UNIQUE constraint failed: execution.query_id, execution.handler_id Unable to fetch row  --  [(null)]
```

Comment: Stdout of a crashed session maybe has more info

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r not sure what stdout is, but please see what I added now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in 0.17.2. The fix will be released with 0.18

See this issue https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert/issues/1033

A workaround is to delete  `~/.config/albert/core.db`